# NgModule dynamically loaded - check if already present

Tags: angular

We load a lot of modules by SystemJs and Angular 2 compiler...for example:

```js
 System.import(modulePath)
       .then((module: any) => {
            moduleType = module[moduleTypeName];
            componentType = module[componentTypeName];
                            return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(<any>moduleType);
                        })......
```

Now i just would like to know, next cycle for example, if module is already loaded and compiled by angular 2.... so i could get directly right componentFactory and create a new one without load again and again modules!